# FileNotFoundError at /user/profile/edit [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'user_3/profile.jpg'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I`m beginner of django and try to make small newsfeed like instagram.
And I have issue, after I connect the backend storage to S3 for media and staticfiles, my media file has some problem.
I have error "FileNotFoundError at /user/profile/edit [Errno 2] No such file or directory" or "This backend doesn't support absolute paths." or "Key error 'JPG'".

I have searched about this problem, and there is something about file format between S3 and pillow is different. But when I try to save pic.save(self.picture.name) or pic.save(self.picture.path), then I have key error about image format.
But it upload to S3 properly, just python can not find it.
I have no idea which part is wrong.
Can someone please tell me?

#### model.py

```
def user_directory_path_profile(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    profile_pic_name = 'user_{0}/profile.jpg'.format(instance.user.id)
    full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, profile_pic_name)

    if os.path.exists(full_path):
        os.remove(full_path)

    return profile_pic_name


def user_directory_path_banner(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    banner_pic_name = 'user_{0}/banner.jpg'.format(instance.user.id)
    full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, banner_pic_name)

    if os.path.exists(full_path):
        os.remove(full_path)

    return banner_pic_name


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_info = models.TextField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=user_directory_path_profile, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Picture')
    banner = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=user_directory_path_banner, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Banner')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        SIZE = 250, 250

        if self.picture:
            pic = Image.open(self.picture)
            pic.thumbnail(SIZE, Image.LANCZOS)
            pic.save(self.picture.name)
```

#### settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'djfans/static'),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

I searched some answers like a similar problem, and things were like

```
image.save(name)
```

or

```
storage_path = storage.open(photo.img.name, "wb")
resized_image.save(storage_path, 'png')
storage_path.close()
```

something like this, but it`s not working(or I did something wrong again).
Mega thanks for your help.

Comment: Which lines of code give you these errors?  We can't run your app, especially not in a server/S3 environment.

Comment: Thank you for comment. 
I just solved problem, like other issues, it was problem because of the saving method. 
And I just forgot to return object in the end.. 
Just in case someone will have the same problem, this one work fine.

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage
if self.picture:
            pic = Image.open(self.picture)
            pic.thumbnail(SIZE, Image.LANCZOS)
            storage_path = storage.open(self.picture.name, "wb")
            pic.save(storage_path)
            storage_path.close()

            return self
```

Comment: add your solution as an answer so others can easily find it.